# Where is the MariaDB password stored on Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, passwords, mariadb

Where is the MariaDB root password stored on Linux? The version is 10.3.18. I've looked in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but it's not in there. I don't want to change the password I just want to see what it is.

Comment: it stored in the table user in the schema mysql. you can get this information with **select user,password from  mysql.user;**

Answer (score 0):

It's not stored in a form you can read back, it will be hashed and scrambled beyond recovery. You cannot see what it is.

The exception to this is when MySQL boots up for the first time on a clean install it generates a new root password and *logs this* in the standard MySQL log. Look in `/var/log/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation describes a way to get into MySQL/MariaDB if you forget the root password.  For security, it only works from the same machine, and only if you have OS's root permission.

Non-root passwords, like the root password, are stored via one-way encryption.